# How can I change the token format of ReplaceTokens filter in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have tokens in the file in a bash format looking something like this:

```
PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
```

How can I change ReplaceTokens filter so that it would respect the bash format?

```
copy{ 
  into something
  from somethingelse
  filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [PASSWORD:'123456'])  
}
```

Comment: just a little search away: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html, look at the different `filter` variants.

Comment: thanks. Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 1):

ReplaceTokens supports a begin and end token, so you could do this:

```
    filter( ReplaceTokens,
        beginToken : '$',
        endToken : '',
        tokens: [PASSWORD:'123456']
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use expand property of a copy task:

https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:expand(java.util.Map)

```
task copyProductionConfig(type: Copy) {
  from 'source'
  include 'config.properties'
  into 'build/war/WEB-INF/config'
  expand([
    databaseHostname: 'db.company.com',
    version: versionId,
    buildNumber: (int)(Math.random() * 1000),
    date: new Date()
  ])
}
```